# Frame by frame control of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to move frame by frame in a YouTube video?

I don't want to download the video.

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. can jump to sections in a video. That's cool, but I would like more navigation options.

Comment: Do you need to do this for many videos or just a single video? If one, just download the file and use VLC/QuickTime to play the .flv or .m4v.

Comment: That looks like my only option so far. It would be nice if worked in the browser, though.

Comment: I recall the earliest video players offered this feature. Why every video player doesn't natively offer this feature is beyond me, but this definitely is a peeve of mine.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Pause the video. Press <kbd>.</kbd> to go one frame forward. <kbd>,</kbd> to go one frame back. I use these whenever I use others’ animated videos as references.

Comment: Using Chrome with the Youtube HTML5 player, these actually change the "speed" of the video :
- "dot" increases the video speed (x2, x4)
- "comma" decreases it (/2, /4, etc.)

Comment: In safari, using the html5 player this behaves exactly as described.

Comment: @John Not for me , I use HTML5 also, in Chrome also as you, and they do what this answer says.

Comment: Youtube shortcuts: https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/going-google/accessibility/google-keyboard-shortcuts---youtube

Answer (score 9):

There's a Web App and a Google Chrome Extension which allow you to move frame by frame through a YouTube video:

- [Watch Frame by Frame Web App](http://www.watchframebyframe.com)

  - Frame by frame
  - Slow motion
  - Current time in milliseconds
- [Frame by Frame Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frame-by-frame/elkadbdicdciddfkdpmaolomehalghio)

  - Frame by frame

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the YouTube enhance userscript;

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/33042

> Media Controller :
>
> ☯ Step back: Go backward to the nearest video keyframe and pause.
>
> ☯ Step forward: Go to the next frame and pause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting a Server Error at the moment for that link.

Comment: It was down but seems to be working again now.

Answer (score 2):

Period (.) goes one frame forward

Comma (,) goes on frame backward

Right Arrow goes forward 5 seconds

Left Arrow goes backward 5 seconds

L goes forward 10 seconds

J goes backward 10 seconds

Comment: Forgot to add, when going frame by frame the YouTube video has to be paused.

Answer (score 1):

Your right and left arrow keys will step forwards and backwards.

Source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GRsRiu2zSA

Comment: not one frame. in my browser, right arrow steps forward 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

[Scroll Frame](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frame-scroll/llinnoiobmohhbhnkflcflojcomgonge) does this. Simple UI buttons, or mouse scroll.

Comment: This is considered a oneliner. Add more info to your post as the link may get broken in time.